# How can I calclulate the diskspace of a remote machine using java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Can anyone suggest me how can I **modify the below code which is currently calculating the free disk space(C:) of my local system**(Windows OS) **to calculate the free disk space (C:) of the remote machine**(Windows OS) using java?

```
import java.io.File;

public class DiskMemory
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        File file = new File("C:");
        //total disk space in bytes.
        long totalSpace = file.getTotalSpace(); 
        //unallocated free disk space in bytes.
        long usableSpace = file.getUsableSpace(); 
        //unallocated free disk space available to current user.
        long freeSpace = file.getFreeSpace(); 



        System.out.println(" ==Total Memory Allocation == ");
        System.out.println("Total size : " + totalSpace + " bytes");
        System.out.println("Space free : " + usableSpace + " bytes");
        System.out.println("Space free : " + freeSpace + " bytes");

        System.out.println(" === mega bytes ===");
        System.out.println("Total size : " + totalSpace /1024 /1024 + " mb");
        System.out.println("Space free : " + usableSpace /1024 /1024 + " mb");
        System.out.println("Space free : " + freeSpace /1024 /1024 + " mb");
    }
}
```

Comment: Of what remote machine?

Comment: How are you connecting to the remote machine?

Comment: You have to run this on the remote machine instead.  How you do that depends on the level of access you have to that machine

Comment: it is a remote machine which I can login from my local system run-->mstsc command. It is based on Windows Operating system

Comment: but Peter I have 9 such machine and if I go and manually check for all the machines by logging in then it will consume a lot of time. The idea of the code is to automate the entire process of calculation of the free and total disk space

Comment: Dojo_user: what is stopping you from installing a remote connection, so you can run the code on each machine seperately from one main terminal?

Comment: Stultuske, can you please elaborate a bit about the approach you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into using commons VFS for accessing the remote file systems and determining the file size

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/

This would allow you to get a file representing the remote directory (FileObject in VFS lingo) and get the size much in the same way you are doing already.  Have a look at the website for an example. You could use VFS to query your local disk space as well.

Answer (score 3):

After looking at Apache's VFS, I found it overly complicated to get disk space usage, and it relies on jCIFS ( https://jcifs.samba.org/ ), which will do it with less hassel.

```
SmbFile file = new SmbFile("smb://[user]:[pass]@[server]/[share]");
System.out.println(file.getDiskFreeSpace()); // Space free on share
System.out.println(file.length()); // Total space available on share
```

Comment: by this will it be possible to get free space of Ubuntu OS from windows OS?

Comment: If that Unix host has Samba I don't see why not, but I couldn't answer that directly. Our setup was for a Unix host to get information on Windows disks. We used a  SSH connection with a special minimal access user and just parsed the output of the "df -Pk" command for disk usage information.

For SSH connections, we used JSch ( http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ ).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have access to all the machines whose disk space you want to calculate, you can write a simple client server program to solve the problem. 
The high level overview of the system will be the following :

Let C be your machine, let s1, s2, s3, ..., sN be the N machines whose disk space you want on C.

On each the s machines, (s1, s2, etc), you need to run a server which is listening on some port (choose a port > 1024). 
On machine C, there should be a client which will connect to all the s machines to get the usage.

Look up client server programming in java, it's pretty straightforward.